# HP P4014n will only print letter size

Tags: hp, troubleshooting, desktop, printer

Had a user using HP P4014n locally, device suddenly stopped printing, I removed the printer, and uninstalled and reinstalled the printer drivers. Then readded printer. Now it will not auto-detect paper size that is in the tray.

I've tried going into the preferences and manually setting it to the correct size just to test and it will not work. Prior to the removal and re-installation of the printer it would auto-detect just fine.

I cannot for the life of me figure out how to fix this. I'm using PCL6 driver from HP. Printer is connected over USB locally to the computer that the user is printing from.

Has anyone encountered this with HP printers and resolved it?

Comment: When you remove & re-add the tray, does it ask the paper size on the LCD ? if yes, enter it there correctly with the correct format.

Comment: @yagmoth555 I will make sure I check that, once the correct size is chosen, I assume that it will save that setting so that it will select that when the tray is resized. Is this correct?

Comment: Yes, in the driver, the auto-select will check that setting from the printer. Like too if by error it's letter but heavy size, it can not fit if you want to print to standard sheet

Comment: A side note, if letter are set on two tray (same paper size on two tray), the auto-select take the first tray.